# Javascript Content Multiple Sliders Same Page

Tags: javascript, html

I have a question, if someone can help will be greatly appreciated as I've been trying and trying with no success.

http://samiconcepts.com/rise-sports2

In this link, scroll a little down and you'll see 4 video content sliders (these sliders are controlled via the dots. You click dot, slide changes).

Now, I duplicated the HTML for the 4 sliders, but ONLY the first slider works when I click the dots, not the second, third or fourth. I am thinking that the Javascript is only allowing for 1 slider to work on the page at a time.

How can I have it so that all the sliders work? (might need JS/HTML tweaking)?

I am posting code below. Thank you for your consideration to help.

**Javascript**

```
// vars
'use strict'
var testim = document.getElementById("testim"),
        testimDots = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementById("testim-dots").children),
    testimContent = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementById("testim-content").children),
    testimLeftArrow = document.getElementById("left-arrow"),
    testimRightArrow = document.getElementById("right-arrow"),

    currentSlide = 0,
    currentActive = 0,
    testimTimer,
        touchStartPos,
        touchEndPos,
        touchPosDiff,
        ignoreTouch = 30;
;

window.onload = function() {

    // Testim Script
    function playSlide(slide) {
        for (var k = 0; k < testimDots.length; k++) {
            testimContent[k].classList.remove("active");
            testimContent[k].classList.remove("inactive");
            testimDots[k].classList.remove("active");
        }

        if (slide < 0) {
            slide = currentSlide = testimContent.length-1;
        }

        if (slide > testimContent.length - 1) {
            slide = currentSlide = 0;
        }

        if (currentActive != currentSlide) {
            testimContent[currentActive].classList.add("inactive");            
        }
        testimContent[slide].classList.add("active");
        testimDots[slide].classList.add("active");

        currentActive = currentSlide;

        clearTimeout(testimTimer);
        testimTimer = setTimeout(function() {
            playSlide(currentSlide += 1);
        }, testimSpeed)
    }

    testimLeftArrow.addEventListener("click", function() {
        playSlide(currentSlide -= 1);
    })

    testimRightArrow.addEventListener("click", function() {
        playSlide(currentSlide += 1);
    })    

    for (var l = 0; l < testimDots.length; l++) {
        testimDots[l].addEventListener("click", function() {
            playSlide(currentSlide = testimDots.indexOf(this));
        })
    }

    playSlide(currentSlide);

    // keyboard shortcuts
    document.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
        switch (e.keyCode) {
            case 37:
                testimLeftArrow.click();
                break;

            case 39:
                testimRightArrow.click();
                break;

            case 39:
                testimRightArrow.click();
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    })

        testim.addEventListener("touchstart", function(e) {
                touchStartPos = e.changedTouches[0].clientX;
        })

        testim.addEventListener("touchend", function(e) {
                touchEndPos = e.changedTouches[0].clientX;

                touchPosDiff = touchStartPos - touchEndPos;

                console.log(touchPosDiff);
                console.log(touchStartPos); 
                console.log(touchEndPos);   


                if (touchPosDiff > 0 + ignoreTouch) {
                        testimLeftArrow.click();
                } else if (touchPosDiff < 0 - ignoreTouch) {
                        testimRightArrow.click();
                } else {
                    return;
                }

        })
}
```

**HTML**

```
<section id="testim" class="testim">
            <div class="wrap">

                <span id="right-arrow" class="arrow right fa fa-chevron-right"></span>
                <span id="left-arrow" class="arrow left fa fa-chevron-left "></span>
                <ul id="testim-dots" class="dots">
                    <li class="dot active"></li>
                   <li class="dot"></li>
                    <li class="dot"></li>

                   <li class="dot"></li>
                </ul>
                <div id="testim-content" class="cont">

                    <div class="active">

                                  <a class="js-rytl--link" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rb0UmrCXxVA"><img class="video1 play" src="/images-rise/vi.jpg"></a><br>


                                 <div class="bla"> <div class="title1-1S">VIDEO 1: </div>
     <div class="title1-2S">SPEED TRAINING</div></div> 
                          <p class="reviewsText1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.</p>  
                    </div>

                    <div>




                                  <a class="js-rytl--link" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rb0UmrCXxVA"><img class="video1 play" src="/images-rise/vi.jpg"></a><br>


                            <div class="bla">   <div class="title1-1S">VIDEO 2: </div>
        <div class="title1-2S">TRAINING</div></div>
                          <p class="reviewsText1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.</p>  
                    </div>

                    <div>

                                                          <a class="js-rytl--link" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rb0UmrCXxVA"><img class="video1 play" src="/images-rise/vi.jpg"></a><br>


                            <div class="bla">      <div class="title1-1S">VIDEO 3: </div>
        <div class="title1-2S">TRAINING</div></div>
                          <p class="reviewsText1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.</p>  
                    </div>

                    <div>

                                  <a class="js-rytl--link" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rb0UmrCXxVA"><img class="video1 play" src="/images-rise/vi.jpg"></a><br>


                               <div class="bla">   <div class="title1-1S">VIDEO 4: </div>
        <div class="title1-2S">TRAINING</div></div>
                          <p class="reviewsText1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.</p>  
                    </div>
</DIV>
             </DIV>
    </section>
```

Comment: Duplicate ID Problem

Comment: Can you show me the fix? I've tried giving different ID's but still didn't work

Comment: change ID to Class

Comment: Can you please be a little more specific, maybe showing where exactly to make the change

Comment: In HTML Change ID to class and same to javascript `testim = document.getElementById("testim"),` to `testim = document.getElementsByClassName("testim")`, ....

Comment: I did it, changed ID to class in HTML and in the JS, but still only the first slider works, not the 2nd 3rd and 4th

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206046/discussion-between-lalji-tadhani-and-samish).